# Chrome extension remove cookies

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

I'm trying to clear the web pages' cookies when the page loads. I do so by sending a message from the content-script to the background, and clear the cookies there, but, I get an empty value in the `cookies.remove` method's callback! and I'm not sure if it remove the cookie or not?

#### manifest.json

```
"host_permissions": [
    "*://*.example.com/*"
],
"permissions": [
    "cookies"
],
```

#### background.js

```
//get all cookies belongs to us and allowed by the host_permissions: 
chrome.cookies.getAll({}, function (cookies) {
    console.log('cookies:', cookies); //<=== Check the cookies I get here below;

    //loop the cookies: 
    cookies.forEach(function (cookie, i) {
        let cookieUrl = "http";
        cookieUrl += (cookie.secure) ? 's' : '';
        cookieUrl += '://' + cookie.domain + cookie.path;

        //remove this cookie: 
        chrome.cookies.remove({
            url: cookieUrl,
            name: cookie.name
        }, function (removedCookie) {
            console.log('removedCookie:', removedCookie); //<=== Why do I get an empty value here? 
        });
    });
});
```

The cookies I get from the `getAll` method looks like this:

```
[
    {
        "domain": ".example.com",
        "expirationDate": 1665373940.320597,
        "hostOnly": false,
        "httpOnly": false,
        "name": "session-js",
        "path": "/",
        "sameSite": "lax",
        "secure": true,
        "session": false,
        "storeId": "0",
        "value": "..."
    }, {
        "domain": ".example.com",
        "expirationDate": 1665373940.320763,
        "hostOnly": false,
        "httpOnly": true,
        "name": "laravel_session",
        "path": "/",
        "sameSite": "lax",
        "secure": true,
        "session": false,
        "storeId": "0",
        "value": "..."
    }
]
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I think your extension is correct.
When I changed it to   "host_permissions": [
    "*://www.yahoo.co.jp/*"
  ] and executed it, I got 3 cookies from www.yahoo.co.jp and deleted them all.

Comment: As the documentation says you need to check chrome.runtime.lastError in the callback. BTW you can remove all cookies for an origin or for all origins with just one call of chrome.browsingData API.

Comment: Thank you guys! this was helpful! -- @wOxxOm I made sure the cookies were removed by re-calling the `coookies.getAll` method AGAIN inside of the callback of the `cookies.remove` method, and nothing was there, so, I knew the cookies were removed successfully, however, I'm still curious why do I get an empty value in the callback's `details` argument? the value of `chrome.runtime.lastError` is `undefined`!

Comment: It's a bug in Chrome or in the documentation.